# How to reset failures count to zero when using dbms_jobs?

Tags: oracle, jobs

Is there some way to reset the failure count column to 0 in `dba_jobs` view? Sometimes a job fail and after fix it I need to wait the next scheduled execution, during this time I'd like to reset to 0 to remove the alert from the monitoring tool.

Comment: In the process of fixing the job, presumably you need to run the job to confirm the fix don't you?  If you manually run the job with a `dbms_job.run` to test your fix rather than manually running whatever process the job calls, that resets the failure count to 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can run sql as below:

```
update job$ set failures=0 where failures<>0
```